# Livecycle javascript with repeating pages and table rows, subsequent pages do not perform js

Tags: javascript, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I have a dynamic LiveCycle form that repeats pages and has repeating table rows based on XML. I have added some JavaScript code to "hide" rows if there is no data in that row. First page works well but subsequent pages do not process the JavaScript.

Here is some sample JS I have on the table :

```
for(i = 0; i < Table1._Row2.count; i++) {
    if (xfa.form.resolveNode("Row.Details.Page2.table1sf.Table1.Row2[" + i + "].reqName").rawValue == null) {
        xfa.form.resolveNode("Row.Details.Page2.table1sf.Table1.Row2[" + i + "]").presence = "hidden";
    }
}
```

I want the rest of the pages behave like the first.

Comment: I have reformatted your code but the first line after the `for` loop makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah I am also super confused by what you are trying to do there

Comment: Its iterating thru the rows of a table. If it finds an empty cell then it hides the row completely.

Comment: Update: I changed "Row.Details.Page2.table1sf.Table1" to just 'this' and it works better. Must have to do with the DOM path working on the first page but breaking on any other page.